# Incorrect results when using last_value()

Tags: mysql, sql

This is the table:

| id | region | variety | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Alexander Valley | Cabernet Sauvignon | 35 |
| 2 | Alexander Valley | Cabernet Sauvignon | 45 |
| 3 | Alexander Valley | Merlot | 19 |
| 4 | California | Sauvignon Blanc | 8 |
| 5 | California | Pinot Noir | 17 |

I wanted to find out for each region, the cheapest and most expensive variety, so the output should be:

| region | expensive | cheap |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Alexander Valley | Cabernet Sauvignon | Merlot |
| California | Pinot Noir | Sauvignon Blanc |

I was able to get the correct result using two `first_value()`

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT region,
  FIRST_VALUE(variety) OVER (PARTITION BY region ORDER BY price DESC) AS expensive,
  FIRST_VALUE(variety) OVER (PARTITION BY region ORDER BY price) AS cheapest
FROM wine_list
```

I thought it would be equivalent to the following query

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT region,
  FIRST_VALUE(variety) OVER (PARTITION BY region ORDER BY price DESC) AS expensive,
  LAST_VALUE(variety) OVER (PARTITION BY region ORDER BY price DESC) AS cheapest
FROM wine_list
```

However now my output is:

| region | expensive | cheap |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Alexander Valley | Cabernet Sauvignon | Cabernet Sauvignon |
| Alexander Valley | Cabernet Sauvignon | Merlot |
| California | Pinot Noir | Pinot Noir |
| California | Pinot Noir | Sauvignon Blanc |

Why is my output wrong? I am so baffled.

Comment: Please always tag your SQL requests with the DBMS you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default window for `FIRST_VALUE` and `LAST_VALUE` is `ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW`. I.e. it is the first resp. last value "so far".

You want it for the whole dataset, however, so you must explicitely describe the window range:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  region,
  FIRST_VALUE(variety) OVER 
    (PARTITION BY region ORDER BY price DESC
     ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS expensive,
  LAST_VALUE(variety) OVER 
     (PARTITION BY region ORDER BY price DESC
      ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS cheapest
FROM wine_list;
```

Comment: Thank you. I understand now. I re-read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_first-value. It does make sense

Comment: One note, it's redundant to use `ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW` if you don't want to set your own row range